# DynamicSQL query for date calculation

Tags: dynamic-sql

In Dynamic SQL I need to calculate the difference in Date and a Number

Error while running the below query,

```
Declare @sqlstring VARCHAR(MAX)

Declare @GCValue INT

Set @GCValue=10

set @sqlstring = 'SELECT Id, getdate() - (FirstDate + ' + @GCValue +' ) from
Table where Id=1234'

EXECUTE(@Sqlstring)
```

E.g. let say GetDate() = 26 July 2019  and FirsDate = 1 July 2019  and @GCValue=10

Query Should return Difference of Days between above i.e. 26 July 2019 - (1 July 2019 + added 10 days so it became 11July2019) = 15 Days.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more: why do you need dynamic sql? Is it part of the specification of the problem, or your way to approach it?

Comment: Hi Giorgos, this is existing written code where we running the code for update and insert in table and it is just Stored proceedure we firing through some Scheduler job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever your reasons, here is a solution (not an elegant one :-) ) assuming SQL Server:

`DECLARE @sqlstring VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @GCValue varchar(10);
SET @GCValue = '10';
SET @sqlstring = 'SELECT Id, DATEDIFF(dd, getdate(), FirstDate + ' + @GCValue + ' ) from Table where Id=1234';
EXECUTE(@sqlstring);`

You have to change @GCValue's data type to varchar (or explicictly convert it from int, as in `cast(@GCValue as varchar(10))` to use it in string concatenation operations. And you can use DateDiff to compute the difference in days (`dd` parameter).

Comment: But you should be aware that dynamic sql is seldom the recommended approach, nor is use of "execute" the best way to go; see for example `sp_executesql`

Comment: Many thanks Giorgos, the only issue is why the same doesn't work if I try to insert it in table e.g.  @sqlstring ='INSERT into Table (ItemId, EffDate)
 SELECT Id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD,1,GetDate()), 101) from Item '